# Unable to add new domain to server via bind

Tags: dns, bind, vps

I've tried several times to add a new domain to my server. I have the main domain working properly which I added via BIND

```
/etc/bind/named.conf.local for the main domain:
zone "maindomain.com" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/zones/maindomain.com.db";
        };
```

The domain has the following nameservers: ns1.maindomain.com and ns2.maindomain.com (self-appointed, work fine so far)

The zone configuration for this domain:

```
$TTL 1500
@  IN SOA maindomain.com. root (
                             2007062703        ;serial
                             28800             ;refresh
                             3600              ;retry
                             604800            ;expire
                             38400 )           ;minimum 25 minutes
@ IN A 92.114.82.208
maindomain.com.      IN      NS      ns1.maindomain.com.
ns1    IN      A       92.114.82.208
ns2    IN      A       92.114.82.208
ns3 IN A 92.114.82.208
```

Anyhow, I have not managed to add a new domain on the same server with the following configuration:

```
/etc/bind/named.conf.local now has:
zone "maindomain.com" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/zones/maindomain.com.db";
        };
zone "maindomain2.com" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/zones/maindomain2.com.db";
        };
```

maindomain2.conf zone:

```
$TTL 1500
@  IN SOA maindomain2.com. root (
                             2007062703        ;serial
                             28800             ;refresh
                             3600              ;retry
                             604800            ;expire
                             38400 )           ;minimum 25 minutes
@ IN A 92.114.82.208
ns    IN      A       92.114.82.208
ns2    IN      A       92.114.82.208
```

Through this configuration I have appointed the NS to maindomain2.com via the NameServer edit function:
    ns.maindomain2.com 
    ns2.maindomain2.com

Appointed them to 92.114.82.208

Having done this the domain has not linked with the server, tried several restarts, several other configurations which were not successful - the NS do not solve, the domain does not solve to DNS.

Any ideas, please?